# Ruby Multithreading timing versus cpu core count

Tags: ruby, multithreading, fork, cpu

I wrote the following code to test single versus multi threading in Ruby. I loop an array of two elements and sleep for 1 second sequentially ( ~ 2 second execution time). I then do the same thing but fork the process each time ( ~ 1 second execution time since the two sleep command are running in parallel ). This made sense to me.

As I increased the size of the array, i.e. more iterations, I noticed that the multi-threading always returned in ~ 1 second. I am running on an Ubuntu instance on VirtualBox and have 1 processing unit available to me:

```
root@vbox-docker:~/docker-projects/hello-world/lib# nproc
1
```

My assumption was that as I increased the number of iterations, the multi-threading would take longer as all the processing units were consumed. The only other thing I can think of is the clock speed is pushing many of these threads through simultaneously and I need to increase the iterations even more in order to see a slow down on the multi-threaded side.

My question is this: Am I thinking about this correctly? Does my logic make sense? Is this an accurate test to see the of results of single versus multi-threaded application?

Check out the below Ruby script, and run if you so choose and please provide feedback.

thanks in advance!

**Edit: Setting the iteration to 500 and the sleep to 5 seconds caused the multi-threaded section to take 22 seconds and change. Interesting.**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

#Do a single threaded run, timing each iteration of the array [0,1], doing two iterations because of two elements
before = Time.now
[0,1].each do |i|
  sleep 1
end
after = Time.now
delta = (after - before) * 1000.0
puts "Single-threaded: #{delta} milliseconds" #Should be 1000 miliseconds X number of elements in the array (2)

#Do a multi threaded run, timing each iterationg of the array [0,1], doing two iterations because of the two elements
before = Time.now
[0,1].each do |i|
  fork do #Instead of running each operation sequentially, run each process in a different thread
    sleep 1
  end
end
Process.waitall
after = Time.now
delta = (after - before) * 1000.0
puts "Multi-threaded: #{delta} milliseconds" #Should be 1000 miliseconds X 1 while array length < CPU Core count
```

Comment: Forking is not threading, and all you're doing is forking off a process and then sleeping it - you're not actually doing any computational work. What you're observing in your 500 iterations test is probably the overhead cost of forking new processes. What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: @ChrisHeald should I modify my script to use Threads instead and run try testing that then?

Comment: It depends on what you're actually trying to test. So far it's unclear - you have to be doing some kind of work to test parallelism. You can sleep as many processes or threads as you can spawn.

Comment: @ChrisHeald I am trying to demonstrate some the benefit of multithreading versus singlethreading by performing the same action under both circumstances.

Comment: Other issues aside, MRI doesn't use multiple cores. You'd need to use JRuby or Rubinius to take advantage of real parallelism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To measure concurrency, you'll need to do some work. Here's an implementation which computes the Fibbinaci sequence (in an intentionally slow manner).

```
require 'thread'
require 'benchmark'

def fibbinaci(n=33)
  return n if n <= 1
  fibbinaci(n-1) + fibbinaci(n-2)
end

LOOPS = 5

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("Single threaded") do
    LOOPS.times { fibbinaci }
  end

  x.report("Multithreaded") do
    LOOPS.times.map do
      Thread.new { fibbinaci }
    end.each(&:join)
  end

  x.report("Forked") do
    LOOPS.times do
      fork do
        fibbinaci
      end
    end
    Process.waitall
  end unless RUBY_PLATFORM == "java"
end
```

This gives something like:

```
$ ruby fib.rb
                 user       system     total    real
Single threaded  4.050000   0.000000   4.050000 (  4.054188)
Multithreaded    4.100000   0.000000   4.100000 (  4.114595)
Forked           0.000000   0.000000   4.000000 (  2.054361)
```

This is expected - Ruby uses green threads, which means that a single Ruby process can't consume more than 1 CPU core at a time. My machine has 2 cores, so it runs roughly twice as fast when forking (permitting for forking overhead).

If I run this under JRuby, which *does* have native threads (ie, actual in-process concurrency) I get something like:

```
$ ruby fib.rb
                user        system    total     real
Single threaded 27.850000   0.100000  27.950000 ( 27.812978)
Multithreaded   27.870000   0.060000  27.930000 ( 14.355506)
```

The in-process threads do halve the runtime of the task (though, yikes, that appears to be one that JRuby is particularly bad at).

You might wonder why Ruby would offer threading if it can't use more than one core per process - it's because you can still do work across threads when waiting on IO! If you have an application that spends a lot of time talking to network sockets (eg making database queries) then you will see concurrency gains from multithreading by letting other threads work while you're blocking on a socket.